# Jquery how to remove css :after styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

removeHi how can i remove using jquery styles after my element.

I have following:

```
    .arrow {

        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 60%;
        right: 60%;
        left: 20%;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .arrow:after {
        left: 100%;
        bottom: 0px;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-width: 15px;
        border-bottom: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
        border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    }
```

and my question is how can i remove the styles `.arrow:after` using jquery and later apply it again ?

http://jsfiddle.net/765rzuy3/

Comment: You'd probably be better off changing the stylesheet so that it had a different class name before `:after` and then using JavaScript to add and remove that class name from the element.

Comment: Question not clear @vardius. Can u descried more

Comment: Use a different class name to assign `:after` or `:before` pseudo class styles. Later you can remove those class name using using javascript.

Comment: here is jssfiddle i made for you guys.
http://jsfiddle.net/765rzuy3/
i just want to change the arrows you can see on the corners. only one be displayed

Comment: @Vardius check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/765rzuy3/1/)

Comment: you had nice idea, but you can still display both at the same time.
here check it how i solve it. if you want you can post it as answer
http://jsfiddle.net/765rzuy3/2/